# facebook api and android

Tags: android, facebook

I want to use the facebook  RSS feeds in my android application.
I already installed facebook api. but I find difficult to use RSS feeds.
if you have a tutorial or give me an advice to thank you very much.

Comment: facebook RSS feeds? Can you provide more information?

Comment: I want to use RSS already exist in facebook, in my application. that is to say view  rss feeds on android application

Comment: i want to have a like reader rss feeds using facebook api

Comment: Can you provide url or call that you should make to view that RSS?

Comment: i want to view like this url :"http://fr-fr.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=189333421079384&format=atom10"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use the Facebook API, this is a public RSS feed, so you can just make do a httprequest and parse the XML...

See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1253788/simple-rss-parser-for-android

Comment: it does not work for page format = atom10.
it works only for pages on xml extension

Comment: if you have the code project of using the url feeds/atom.please post it.i really need it.thanks